# How to use instance scope in FieldEditorPreferencePage

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, preferences

According to this article http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_load_and_save_plug-in_preferences%3F we're supposed to use preferences as shown below.

```
Preferences prefs = new InstanceScope().getNode(MY_PLUGIN_ID);
```

How do I put it in a field editor preference page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ScopedPreferenceStore`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/preferences/ScopedPreferenceStore.html) and override [`IPreferencePage.doGetPreferenceStore()`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/preference/IPreferencePage.html) to make it available for the dialog.